# How to render inside image tag in svg

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, tags

Here i struggling to generate SVG file with image tag.In image tags, `XLINK:HREF` will shown properly image path but not rendered image while preview image.

HERE MY SAMPLE SVG CODE:

```
<svg width="525" height="300" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

 <g display="" id="front">
  <title>Front 1</title>
  <image xlink:href="/uploads/image_gallery/portrait/879795_print_plus.jpg" src="/uploads/image_gallery/portrait/879795_print_plus.jpg" id="svg_1" height="400" width="400" y="0" x="86"></image>
  <image x="0" y="0" width="5" height="5" xlink:href="http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png"></image>
  <rect stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" fill="#FFF" id="svg_2" height="202" width="202" y="67" x="35"></rect>
  <ellipse ry="77" rx="122" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" fill="#FFF" id="svg_3" cy="82" cx="275"></ellipse>
  <line fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" id="svg_4" y2="197" x2="109" y1="75" x1="363"></line>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Encrypted Image SRC also not rendered properly How to rendered image while preview in svg files?Is there any mistake ?

Comment: Where's your javascript? Please add it to the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson..above svg code is get form svg files..it stored in svg files when i viewed in that svg file image doesn't shown properly. it results only empty image!

Comment: Why does your title mention javascript and why are you using javascript and jquery tags then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google image is white in the area you're displaying. Making it larger makes it display for me.

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="35" height="35" xlink:href="http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png"></image>
```